# Can you use any application whilst it is being updated

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

Is it possible to use any application while it is being updated from the Mac App Store?

Comment: during the download yes, during the install no. wondering why are you asking anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Under **System Preferences / Software Update** you can choose *Automatically check for updates* which will enable the *Download newly available updates in the background* option.

This is quite self-explanatory. It will **just download** the update, letting you use the application while the download is active, and when the download is complete, you'll be prompted, through Notification Center, to **Install** the update.

Comment: that only work for the system updates, not for any particular application updates e.g; xCode etc.

Comment: It should, as [it](http://fairerplatform.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/os-x-mountain-lion-software-update1.jpeg) says *Software update keeps OS X and apps from the Mac App Store up to date*.